# How Can i count multple columns?

Tags: sql-server-2008

[Here is my Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6k3CQ.jpg)

I want to count reference number and per permit ex. BP, AP, OP

My Sample Query

```
SELECT 
C.CompanyName, 
A.ReferenceNumber, 
    Count(CR.BP, 
          CR.AP,  
          CR.SP, 
          CR.FP, 
          CR.EP, 
          CR.ELP, 
          CR.MP, 
          CR.EGPP, 
          CR.OP, 
          CR.EPTO, 
          CR.ELPTO, 
          CR.MPTO, 
          CR.FSIC, 
          CR.AI, 
          CR.EPTO_R, 
          CR.ELPTO_R, 
          CR.MPTO_R, 
          CR.LOA) 
From Companies AS C 
    inner join ApplicationDetails as A on(C.CompanyId = A.CompanyID) 
    inner join CertificateRecords as CR on(A.ReferenceNumber = CR.ReferenceNumber) 
group by A.ReferenceNumber
```

ERROR is The Count function requires 1 argument(s).

Comment: Have you tried something yet?

Comment: im new in sql sorry

Comment: Edit your question and show us sample input, output, and the query you have tried so far.

Comment: did you look at the error message? you count has multiple arguments in it, split it up

Comment: You will also need to add `CompanyName` to the group by clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Count` refers to rows, not columns.
There for, it makes no sense to use it on multiple columns.
You can either use a column name, an asterisk or a constant (the last 2 are equivalent).
The reason for these options is that `count` ignores `null` values - so you can use it in 2 different ways.

When using a column name, you will get the number of values in that column (per group, if you are using it with `group by`. Note that `null` is not considered a value here, so if your column is nullable, you'll get only the number of rows where it's not `null`.

When using asterisk or a constant, `count` will not ignore `null` values, even if all the columns in a row are contains `null` - that row will still get counted.

Here is a quick demo I've made to illustrate it:

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    col1 int NULL,
    col2 int NULL
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
(1,1),
(1,2),
(1,3),
(1, NULL),
(2,1),
(2,2),
(2,3),
(2, NULL),
(NULL, 1),
(NULL, 2),
(NULL, 3),
(NULL, NULL)
```

Count with all options:

```
SELECT  col1, 
        COUNT(col2) As ColumnName,
        COUNT(*) Asterisk,
        COUNT(1) Constant
FROM @T
GROUP BY col1
```

Results: (note that the column with the column name ignores the `null` rows)

```
col1    ColumnName  Asterisk    Constant
NULL    3           4           4
1       3           4           4
2       3           4           4
```

Compare `count(*)` with `count(1)`:

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) Asterisk,
        COUNT(1) Constant
FROM @T
```

Results:

```
Asterisk    Constant
12          12
```